# Re-assignment of Macro to Command button when copying file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in XL regarding redefining the Macro assignment of radio button when the source worksheet is copied to a Destination worksheet within a new workbook.

When i click on the radio button in the Destination worksheet, it attempt to open the Source workbook RATHER to run the macro assigned to the button.

I have checked and the Destination workbook DOES indeed have identical copy of the macro, as the original Source workbook. However, by Right clicking / Assign Macro on the radio button, i find that the path STILL points to the source workbook/worksheet.

I tried the following code while running it from the Source worksheet, but it does not work.

Code:

```
wbkDESTINATION.Sheets("1-Start").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").Select
Selection.OnAction = "Sheet1.WEEKLY"
```

I would appreciate your suggestion, how to modify the last `Selection.OnAction` code so that XL knows to pick it from the Destination worksheet, instead of jumping back to the original source workbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!  Just realised you are using Forms controls.  You can ensure you call the desired procedure by explicitly referencing the workbook, like this:

```
wbkDESTINATION.Sheets("1-Start").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 1").Select
Selection.OnAction = ThisWorkbook.name & "!Sheet1.WEEKLY"
```

<strike>I think that although controls appear in the Shapes collection, they are actually OLE objects with their own _click events in the worksheet code module and can't have alternative procedures assigned to them via `onaction`.  The help is predictably vague on this important distinction though.</strike>

I've confirmed this during testing this myself; the controls always reference the _click events in the parent worksheet.  How are you copying the worksheet?  I tried using the user interface, and programmatically from both standard and worksheet code modules and got the same results every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite updated but I 'm posting it for future seekers.

I run into this question as I had exactly the same problem as mentioned. Finally I 've found the following solution and got a hint on how to remove connections from the source-worksheet (if they exist).

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/correcting-shape-assigned-macro-links-after-copying-worksheet-vba